# Proving a set is dense in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$.

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Let $\mathcal{F}(f)  := \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) e^{-ixy} dx \,  $  denote the Fourier transform of a function $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ and let  $C_b^2 (\mathbb{R})  = \{ f \in \mathbb{C}^{\mathbb{R}} \mid f \text{ is twice differentiable and is bounded } \}$.

Then define the set $A$ as follows,

$$ A := \{ f \in C_b^2(\mathbb{R}) \mid \mathcal{F}(f) \in L^1(\mathbb{R}) \text{ and } f \text{ has compact support } \} $$

Prove that $A$ is dense in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$.

Not sure where to start on this. Was considering trying to prove that the condition $\mathcal{F}(f) \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ is superflous, and maybe relating this to the fact that $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ is dense in $L^1(\mathbb{R}).$

Comment: Are you familiar with the Schwartz class?

Comment: Since $f$ is continuous and has compact support, the hypothesis that it is bounded is redundant. Since $f$ is $C^2$ and has compact support, the hypothesis that its Fourier transform is integrable is also redundant. So $A$ is the set of compactly supported $C^2$ functions.

Answer (score 0):

Do this for a closed interval instead of $\mathbb{R}.$ The compact support is superfluous then, and the density is an immediate consequence of the Stone-Weierstrass theorem. Since functions of compact support are dense in $L^1$ (by the usual step function argument), you are done.

Comment: How is "compact support superfluous"? Given some $g\in L^1([a,b]),$ mustn't we still approximate it (in $L^1$) by some $f\in A?$ (i.e. $C^2$ on $\Bbb R$ and compactly supported). And are you applying the "small" SW-theorem? but polynomials don't belong to $A.$